# リモートのmysqlにphpmyadminで接続する際のアクセス拒否エラー

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

CentOSで
(1:Remoteサーバ) mysql
(2:localサーバ) phpmyadmin
のサーバ構成を組んでいます(TCP接続)。

(2)にはphpもphp-mysqlもapacheも入れています。
phpmyadminのログイン画面は出てくるのですが、ユーザ名・パスワードを入力して[実行]ボタンを押したところ、「MySQL サーバにログインできません」とのエラー表示が表示されます。

(1)のmysqld.logを確認すると、

```
2017-04-03T10:52:40.593052Z 11 [Note] Access denied for user '(アカウントにつき削除)'@'gateway' (using password: YES)
```

というログが出ます。この'gateway'というのは何でどこで設定するのでしょうか？

(2)の/etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.phpの設定は修正と見直しは行なっているつもりなのですが。

どなたかご存知の方はご教示お願いします。

Answer (score 1):

MySQLのユーザを作成する際に接続元ホストを指定してください。
指定したホストからの接続のみ許可されます。
ホスト名にはワイルドカード (`%` `_`) が使えますので次のようにすることも可能です。

```
CREATE USER 'myname'@'%.mydomain.com' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
CREATE USER 'myname'@'192.168.0.%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
CREATE USER 'myname'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
```

Answer (score 0):

サーバー側のログに出力されるユーザーの「@」の後ろはサーバーから見たアクセス元のホスト名です。